# Regex python: Return words surrounding character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tokenize

I have a string with millions of words and I would like to have a regex that can return the five words that surround any dollar sign. For example:

```
string = 'I have a sentence with $10.00 within it and this sentence is done. '
```

I would like the regex to return

```
surrounding = ['I', 'have', 'a', 'sentence', 'with', 'within', 'it', 'and', 'this', 'sentence']
```

My ultimate goal would be to tally all of the words that surround a mention of a '$' so the above list would be complete with:

```
final_return = [('I', 1), ('have', 1), ('a', 1), ('sentence', 2), ('with', 1), ('within', 1), ('it', 1), ('and', 1), ('this', 1)]
```

The regex below that I have developed so far can return the string attached to the currency symbol with the surrounding 5 characters. Is there a way to either edit the regex to capture the surrounding five words instead? Should I (and if so, how) use NLTK's tokenizer to achieve this?

```
   import re
 .....\$\s?\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?.....
```

Comment: Are you able to import `regex` module?

Answer (score 1):

Use split to split words, delete non word with isalpha, then count frequency of word in list.

```
string='I have a sentence with $10.00 within it and this sentence is done. '
string1=string.split()
string2=[s for s in string1 if s.isalpha()]
[[x,string2.count(x)] for x in set(string2)] 
#[['and', 1], ['within', 1], ['sentence', 2], ['it', 1], ['a', 1], ['have', 1], ['with', 1], ['this', 1], ['is', 1], ['I', 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful. Anyway that I can return these words numerically ordered?

Answer (score 0):

You can start using below code, i am trying to solve it more simple way.

```
import re

string = 'I have a sentence with $10.00 within it and this sentence is done. '

surrounding  = re.search(r'(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*\$\d+\.?\d{2}?\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)\s*(\w+)', string, flags=0).groups()

print(surrounding )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if Regular expression is a proper choice for this problem. Instead you can extract all the 10 words surrounding a dollar sign buy looping over the words and keeping track of five previously traversed words to be returned whenever you find a match.

In this case you can use `collections.deque()` which is a proper data structure with limited number of items to preserve five previous words. Then you can use a `collections.Counter()` object to return a counter of words within the threshold.

```
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def my_counter(string):
    container = deque(maxlen=5)
    words = iter(string.split())
    def next_five(words):
        for _ in range(5):
            try:
                yield next(words)
            except StopIteration:
                pass

    for w in words:
        if w.startswith('$'):
            yield Counter(chain(container, next_five(words)))
        else:
            container.append(w)
```

Demo:

```
In [8]: s =  ' extra1 extra2 I have a sentence with $10.00 within it and this sentence is done.asdf asdf a b c d e $5 k j n m k gg ee'

In [9]: 

In [9]: list(my_counter(s))
Out[9]: 
[Counter({'I': 1,
          'a': 1,
          'and': 1,
          'have': 1,
          'it': 1,
          'sentence': 2,
          'this': 1,
          'with': 1,
          'within': 1}),
 Counter({'a': 1,
          'b': 1,
          'c': 1,
          'd': 1,
          'e': 1,
          'j': 1,
          'k': 2,
          'm': 1,
          'n': 1})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a regular expression with a counter, like so:

```
(?P<before>(?:\w+\W+){5})
\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?
(?P<after>(?:\W+\w+){5})
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/HSncJY/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?P<before>(?:\w+\W+){5})
    \$\d+(?:\.\d+)?
    (?P<after>(?:\W+\w+){5})
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

sentence = 'I have a sentence with $10.00 within it and this sentence is done. '
words = [Counter(m.group('before').split() + m.group('after').split())
                    for m in rx.finditer(sentence)]
print(words)
```

---

This yields (note that a `Counter` is already a `dict`):

```
[Counter({'sentence': 2, 'I': 1, 'have': 1, 'a': 1, 'with': 1, 'within': 1, 'it': 1, 'and': 1, 'this': 1})]
```